# python class decorator inside method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I try to use decorator pattern for class hierarchy, so I define class decorator as below:

```
def delegate(cls, target='_base'):
    class Wrapper(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.wrapped = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def __getattr__(self, name):
            if hasattr(self.wrapped, name):
                return getattr(self.wrapped, name)
            else:
                return getattr(self.wrapped.__dict__.get(target), name)

    return Wrapper

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
      pass

    def foo(self):
      print('this is foo()')


@delegate
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._base = A()

    def bar(self):
        self.foo()  # self._base.foo() will work

def main():
    B().foo()  #1. works
    B().bar()  #2. attribute not found error
```

Why does the call to self.foo() inside bar() doesn't go throw delegate while #1 works?
To solve it with decorator without hardcode self._base.foo(), must I write method decorator for each method need _base inside B? I try to cut down the boilerplate code.

Comment: this seems a new concept for me ..

Comment: The object that `bar` receives as its `self` argument isn't an instance of `Wrapped`; it's the instance of the original class `B` referenced by `wrapped`.

Comment: @chepner how could I not hard code self._base but annotate/decorate via __getattr__ again in the bar()? Is method decorator the only other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the behavior of decorators is (at least to me) somewhat counterintuitive.

Here's what happens when you check the types of all the objects involved:

```
>>> type(b)
<class 'Wrapper'>

>>> type(b.wrapped)
<class 'B'>

>>> type(b.wrapped._base)
<class 'A'>
```

Because `b` is *really* an instance of `Wrapper` and *not* `B`, when you call `b.foo()`, what's happening is (psuedocode):

```
b.foo() --> Wrapper.__getattr__(foo) --> wrapped._base.foo
```

So `foo` is coming from the `Wrapper` object's `__getattr__` -- not the `Bar` object's.

The problem is that in defining `bar` this way:

```
def bar(self):
    self.foo()
```

`self` does not refer to the `Wrapper` object's `foo` attribute, but the `Bar` object's foo attribute, which doesn't exist.

So, when you call `b.bar()` the method chain is:

```
b.bar() --> Wrapper.__getattr__(bar) --> wrapped.bar() --> wrapped.foo()
```

You can fix this by having `Bar` invoke `self._base.foo()`.

Comment: Thanks. My follow up question is how I could avoid hardcode self._base but annotate/decorate method via \_\_getattr\_\_ again in the bar(), as I have a few places doing the same thing as self.foo(). Although I'm aware that class B is aware of missing foo() impl, I'm exploring if there is trick to make it even foolproof.

Comment: The intention of class decorator in a composite class hierarchy of A, B, C, D from better to worse: 

class decorator >  duplicate \_\_getattr\_\_() in every class  > make every class inherit from abstract utility class which overwrite \_\_getattr\_\_()

Comment: @ying if your goal is just to make completely unrelated `A` and `B` class share the same `foo` method implementation, can't you just have them inherit from a common class `C`? python supports multiple inheritance, so you can have `A` inherit from `X`, `C` and `B` inherit from `Y`, `C`

Comment: what you suggested is my #3 approach, which is the easiest way to achieve the goal. But making class inherit (which martin fowler voices against) in order to share method seems a bit code-smell. I know in python world, seldom ppl cares about code smell. ^_^. For that reason, I choose #2 as a bit better approach given python only need one method \_\_getattr|_\_() dup in each class. The idea of decorator is borrowed from java lib lombok.

Comment: @ying a) I wasn't suggesting inheriting `__getattr__`, i was suggesting inheriting the `foo` method (this is the actual piece of code you want to share right?), but I might be misunderstanding what you're actually trying to do. is your ultimate goal not duplicating `foo`? b) nice to see you've read that book :) inheritance in and of itself isn't one of martin fowler's code smells -- only inheritance in certain situations (also his book is heavy on the java side, which doesn't have a notion of multiple inheritance).

Comment: on the fowler front, from his book *Refactoring*: "There is a popular principle: 'Favor object composition over class inheritance' [...]. Many people take this to mean 'inheritance considered harmful' and claim that we should never use inheritance. I use inheritance frequently, partly because I always know I can use Replace Subclass with Delegate should I need to change it later. Inheritance is a valuable mechanism that does the job most of the time without problems." (also, in the same same section, one of his cons to inheritance is you can only inherit once, which isn't true in python)

Comment: I came from the java side :) Martin advocates inheritance by design for small core infra. For my use case, I have quite a few methods like foo(). In py, I only need to override \_\_getattr\_\_ to delegate all not found attributes in the current class which is nice than java. I just want to push the envelop more to see how much high-order functional lang can do in this case. If I have to choose abstract base class or class decorator + occasional self._base.foo(), personally I probably prefer the latter. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
def delegate(cls, target='_base'):
    class Wrapper(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.wrapped = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def __getattr__(self, name):
            if hasattr(self.wrapped, name):
                return getattr(self.wrapped, name)
            else:
                return getattr(self.wrapped.__dict__.get(target), name)

    return Wrapper

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
      pass

    def foo(self):
      print('this is foo()')


@delegate
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._base = A()

    def bar(self):
        self.foo()

    def thirdbar(self):
        self._base.foo()  # self._base.foo() will work

    def secondbar(self,x):
        x.foo()  # self._base.foo() will work

x=B()
x.foo()  #1. works
x.secondbar(x) #it is working
x.thirdbar()  #it is working
x.bar()   #still not working
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? For instance, explain how this snippet works, and provide links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    B().bar()  #2. attribute not found error
```

Why? You instantiate the `Wrapper` which instantiates the `wrapped`.

You then do a dotted lookup of `'bar'`.

`'bar'` will be found in the wrapped `B`, so this returns a bound method, `self` being the wrapped `B()`, not the `Wrapper()`:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if hasattr(self.wrapped, name): 
        return getattr(self.wrapped, name)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. It seems that subclassing or adding the behavior directly to the class may be preferable to doing this.

It is said that you have to be twice as clever to debug code as to write it. If you're being too clever, you're making it impossible for you to debug it. I would suggest doing something different here.

Comment: The class decorator is to cut down duplicated code (one \_\_getattr\_\_() here in py) in each class in a composite class hierarchy.